# Use Facebook api to determine scope of an access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to determine what scope an access token I have has.

The [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token/) provides me with that information but I can't figure out what api that uses.

I know on the front end you can just call the api and nothing will happen if you already have the scope but I want to do it programatically on the backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/debugging-access-tokens/#step1

You can use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=INPUT_TOKEN&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Where access_token is your [app access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/)